# Use of multiple Regular Expression in C# web crawler

Tags: c#, regex

I am making a web crawler which fetch data from different sites. And for this purpose I use regular expression, it is to much lengthy to write regular expression for each site separately. I want to combine those regular expression and want to work on them.how should i combine them. Please tell me how I'll combine below regular expressions.
Example:

```
Job Title = @"<h2>(.*?)</h2>"

Job Title:</td>.*?<td.*?>(.*?)</td>

Title/Post(.*?)<span.*?>(.*?)</span>

Job Title:</strong>.*?<td.*?>(.*?)</td>
```

Comment: Hint: [***YOU CANNOT PARSE HTML WITH A REGEX.***](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/119527) Just. Don't. Even. Consider. It.

Comment: But it works separately and I just want to combine them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OR-operator |

```
(pattern1)|(pattern2)|(...)
```

Comment: thank you. I  know this one but is there any other possibility to solve it ?

Comment: What's wrong with |-operator? If you want to combine different patterns for different texts you need to use OR (either pattern1 OR pattern2 OR ...). This is the only way to combine them.

Comment: Thank you I will do through this way